# Cut a data.frame into unique halves in R

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, tidyverse, combinatorics

I want to make the columns in my `data.frame` below (*a toy example*) grouped into 2 equally-sized halves. But I want to obtain all possible ***unique*** halves (*each half* = a separate `data.frame`).

For example, in the first possible halves, we may have [`q1`,`q2`,`q3` vs. `q4`,`q5`,`q6`], in the second possible halves we may have [`q1`,`q4`,`q3` vs. `q2`,`q5`,`q6`], in the third possible halves we may have [`q1`,`q3`,`q6` vs. `q2`,`q4`,`q5`], ... (*each 3 columns becomes a new `data.frame`*).

My understanding is that the final output must be stored as a `list` of the resulting `data.frame`s. Is this possible to achieve in `R`?

```
dat <- data.frame(q1=1:5, q2=5:1, q3=2:6, q4=6:2, q5=1:5, q6 =2:6)
```

Comment: Why wont you run a sample on colnames and create 2 dataframes based on the sample???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `combn` to create all possible combinations of column number taken 3 at a time. Use the combinations to subset the dataframe.

```
combn(seq_along(dat), ncol(dat)/2, function(x) 
         list(dat[, x], dat[, -x]), simplify = FALSE)
```

Every list is of length 2 having equal halves of the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! I want to `rowsum` each `data.frame` and then `cor` the results, possible to do this on your output? let me ask that as a different question.

Comment: Like this? `combn(seq_along(dat), ncol(dat)/2, function(x) cor(rowSums(dat[, x]), rowSums(dat[, -x])))`

Comment: Ronak can you possibly check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021588/double-looping-to-get-a-dataframe-in-r-tidyverse)?