# Double looping to get a dataframe in R (tidyverse)

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, tidyverse, lapply

I want to repeat `sample(1:11, 1)` 6 times at 5 different rounds. In the final output, I want a `data.frame` where each round is a row (see below).

Is this achievable in `tidyverse` (e.g., `purrr::map_df`) or BASE R?

```
round1 4 5 6 7 8 9
round2 3 2 1 4 4 1
round3 5 4 2 2 1 1
round4 7 7 7 7 7 1
round5 1 8 8 8 8 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `replicate`

```
t(replicate(5, sample(1:11, 6, replace = TRUE)))
```

As @thelatemail mentioned we can `sample` only once and put the data in a matrix.

```
nr <- 5
nc <- 6
matrix(sample(1:11, nr * nc, replace = TRUE), nr, nc)
```

Comment: Yes, it is similar but it generates a list. So something like this would work: `bind_cols(t(rerun(5, sample(1:11, 6, replace = TRUE))))` where each column is one round.

Comment: If you store the output of above in `mat` and each round is a row. You can use `apply` : `apply(mat, 1,function(x) c(median(x), IQR(x)))`

Comment: If `replace=TRUE`, why not do one sample of 6*5 = 30 values then just feed it into a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

why not use `lapply` to sample 6 elements 5 times. the replace flag in sample gives the chance of pulling the same number more than one time.

```
 data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(1:5,function(x) sample(1:11, 6, replace=T)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As OP asked about `purrr`, here's a tidyverse solution which gets the row names specified in the expected output:

```
library(tidyverse)

rounds <- paste0("round", 1:5) 

rounds %>% 
  setNames(rounds) %>% 
  map_dfc(~sample(1:11, 6, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  t()

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
round1    1   11   10    6    5   10
round2    9    2    3    3    2   10
round3    8    8    2   11    6    7
round4    1    7    8    6   11   10
round5    1    7    7    3    1    8
```